# How can I layout a series of spans, followed by a line break, followed by a button?

Tags: html, css

I'm having the hardest time layout things out like this:

[image]

What I want:

- a few (say 5) elements that are in a horizontal line (the colored bars in the image above)
- a line break
- a button

The 5 elements should be accessible via javascript so I can change style properties (e.g. the background color).

Basically my problem is:

- I can't make them DIVs, or else they won't be horizontal (i.e there will be a line break in between the red and orange, the orange and yellow, and so on)
- If I make them spans, they will line up as above, but there is no line break after them (before the button), even if I put in a `<br>` or `<p>` tag

How can I lay things out like this?

Comment: Have a look at the `display` property in css. `div` can be made `inline-block`s and `button`s can be made `block`s very easily, you are just referring to the defaults.

Comment: There are so many ways you can do, such as float, inline-block, table-cell, flex etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? On SO you are expected to put some effort into trying to solving your problems yourself first. Seeing as your question is an extremely simple one, I think you should be able to solve this by searching for examples online. Try taking a look at the CSS `float` and `display` properties. If you've tried some things and still have specific problems, you're more than welcome to post those.

Comment: Since both the question and some answers mention `<br>` I wanted to chime in — the one and _only_ use I see for **<br>** is to break a line of text at a specific place. All other ways I have seen <br> used can and should be done with CSS. It _is_, after all, the ["HTML Line](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/br.html) [Break Element"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you make them divs?

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le8knxof/) that makes it happen.  It even could handle adaptive resizing gracefully.

HTML:

```
    <div>
    <div class="colorbox" style="background: red"></div>
    <div class="colorbox" style="background: orange"></div>
    <div class="colorbox" style="background: yellow"></div>
    <div class="colorbox" style="background: green"></div>
    <div class="colorbox" style="background: blue"></div>

</div>

<br>
    <button>Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
.colorbox {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-3px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Comment: no need for that `<br>`. Keep your markup clean and stick to css for styling!

Comment: I thought I had tried everything - but inline-block was the key.  (regular inline was what seemed to be causing the lack of the break before the button).  thank you!

Comment: Easy there, Pevara..... this isn't a production-ready code base (nor is a Stack Overflow answer ever meant to be) it's to illustrate that div positioning can be done, as the question asked.   Personally, I wouldn't ever send out an un-styled button nor would I inline styles in production code, either.

Answer (score 1):

As sdcr says, lots of ways! Here's an example of one of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/f3xLvdpm/

The HTML:

```
<div class="red block"></div>
<div class="orange block"></div>
<div class="yellow block"></div>
<div class="green block"></div>
<div class="blue block"></div>
<div class="button">
    <button>BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.block {float: left; width: 100px; height: 120px;}
.red {background-color: red;}
.orange {background-color: orange;}
.yellow {background-color: yellow;}
.green {background-color: green;}
.blue {background-color: bliue;}
.button {clear: both; padding-top: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the span's with a div and use `display: block;` for the div and you could remove the br tag.

Or you could use `display: inline-block;` for span or div tags.